# How to resolve Singleton instance from two different IOC Containers

Tags: ios, swift, inversion-of-control, swinject

I am new to IOC, I am building an Application where we are using IOC containers while discussing we decided an architecture that each module will have two Assemblies one for all module level work which is not exposed outside of that module and one with public access for the functions we want to expose outside.

My problem is I needs to create two IOC containers one at APP level and one at module level and there is a singleton instance which I want to register to both but the moment I resolve them two instances of the class got created on both levels is there a way to just get one instance.

One way is to create a Singleton class and inhibits to generate another instance but that I think will removed the concept of IOC is there any other way to just resolve singleton instance between two IOC containers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to IoC, even I just understand the need of this concept few days ago. But, from your situation, why don't just rely registering the Singleton in one container while the other resolve from the one you registered.
Do this solution break concept of IoC too? I am sorry if this is not answer you search for. I am learning.

Comment: Yes that seems to be a good solution, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You're welcome :) . If you choose the solution, please mark this as accepted answer so others can use the same solution.